# Why restrict to some fixed total time to find an optimal path?

Tags: soft-question, calculus-of-variations, mathematical-modeling

This question is more about conception/modeling than mathematics, however its still mathematics. Every time that I read about calculus of variations I usually found a functional of the following form
$$
F(g):=\int_{a}^b L(t,g(t),g'(t))\,d t\tag1
$$
where $g\in C^2[a,b]$, $g(a)=x_1$ and $g(b)=x_2$ for fixed points $x_1$ and $x_2$, where $a$ and $b$ are assumed fixed but arbitrary. Thus $F$ gives a value related to some path between the points $x_1$ and $x_2$. Now using the Euler-Lagrange equations we can find some candidates for some optimal path in the sense that it minimizes $F$.

Now suppose that $t$ is "time", then for many functions $L$, the optimal path that minimizes $F$, besides a trivial re-parametrization of time by translation, will depend on the total time $b-a$. This seems too restrictive if we want to find an optimal path from all the possible paths that join $x_1$ and $x_2$, that is, why its customary to assume the total time of a functional like (1) to be fixed? Its not more optimal (and natural) to just find the path that minimizes (1) for variable time $b$ (maybe with the restriction that $b\geqslant b_0$ for some fixed $b_0$)?

In other words, how could be useful a model where one assumes the total time of a trajectory a priori? This is not unnecessarily restrictive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On one hand, the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle) uses a fixed time region $[t_i,t_f]$. (We can of course reparametrize time via [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), but that just amounts to kicking the can down the road.) If we try to vary the initial time $t_i$ and/or final time $t_f$, i.e. let them be arbitrary, then the variational problem often becomes ill-posed.
2. On the other hand, there exist variational problems where the time region $[t_i,t_f]$ is free, but in that case it is often needed to fix the [conjugate variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables) (=frequency/energy), cf. e.g. [Maupertius's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle).